# Evaluating differential entropies with Matlab: NaN issue

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, matlab

With Matlab I am trying to evaluate differential entropies. These are integrals like

$$\int_\mathbb{R} p(x) \log (p(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$

where $p(x)$ is a probability density function. My $p(x)$ is computed by an external function. I tried to define

```
g = @(x) x.*log(x);
```

and compute the entropy using

```
integral(@(x) g(p(x)),0,inf)
```

(my $p(x)$ is defined on $[0;+\infty)$). But this fails due to `NaN` issues. However, even if I take the precaution to define `g` as an external function and set `NaN` outputs to zero by a conditional statement, the computation fails. Why?

Consider the following simple example:

I define `g` as an external function to avoid the $0 \log 0$ issue as follows:

```
function y = g(x)

if isnan(x.*log(x))
        y = 0;
else
        y = x.*log(x);
end
```

Now let's try to compute the entropy integral for $p(x) = e^{-x}$, which should obviously return $-1$. But it doesn't:

```
>> p = @(x) exp(-x);
>> integral(@(x) g(p(x)),0,inf)
Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered. 
> In funfun/private/integralCalc>iterateScalarValued at 349
  In funfun/private/integralCalc>vadapt at 133
  In funfun/private/integralCalc at 84
  In integral at 89
```

What is Matlab's problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you've not defined your function `g` correctly in Matlab. The way it's written will not trap [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) cases. As per the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_fun) for the `integral` function:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function y = fun(x) must accept a vector argument, x, and return a vector result, y. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use .* (times) rather than * (mtimes). If you set the 'ArrayValued' option to true, then fun must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.

The `integral` function is vectorized and passes multiple values to your integrand function on each iteration. You've correctly vectorized `x.*log(x)`, but your `if` statement that checks for `NaN` will only be triggered if the first element happens to be `NaN`. Using so-called [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1), you can rewrite `g` concisely as

```
function y = g(x)
y = x.*log(x);
y(isnan(y)) = 0;
```

Then the following code

```
p = @(x)exp(-x);
integral(@(x)g(p(x)),0,Inf)
```

now returns `-1.000000000000000`.

Also, though it may not be numerically scaled as well, you could use the mathematically equivalent `g = @(x)log(x.^x);` instead, which cannot evaluate to `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB does not simplify your integrand - it treats the integrand exactly as specified. So in your first example, MATLAB tries to build a table of the function

$$
\exp(-x)\exp(-x)\log(\exp(-x))
$$

rather than
$$
-x \exp(-x)\exp(-x)
$$

as you would expect.

The first integrand will cause trouble as $x$ becomes very large due to floating point issues. For instance, if you get rid of all the function handles and just try

> integral(@(x) exp(-2.*x).*log(exp(-x)),0, inf)

you get a Nan and the same message.

However, considering how rapidly your integral dies off,

> integral(@(x) exp(-2.*x).*log(exp(-x)),0, 20)

does the job just fine. In fact, using an upper limit of 15 returns a double precision integral of -0.249999999999275, which is far more accurate than anything you might need.

Edited to add: If you want more technical details, for values of x more negative than a certain number, you cause an underflow - a number whose exponent in base 2 is smaller than -1022 cannot be represented in the usual exponent-mantissa format. Underflows can be rounded off to 0 automatically (this is probably what MATLAB does), so numbers like log(exp(-1400)) evaluate to log(0), throwing the NaN.

Comment: Of course I understand that Matlab does not simplify $\log(\exp(-x))$ for me. But I've defined a function `g` precisely to avoid `NaN`s caused by $\log 0$ or $0\log 0$, so I'm puzzled as to what causes the `NaN`s. Also, I am very reluctant to hard-coding of my integration upper limit, as you suggest. Is 20 enough? Or should I set 50? That depends on lots of other parameters. Recall that in my original problem, the pdf is returned by a complicated external function, so I've little insight into that.